# Error when creating S3 bucket notification in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-aws

I'm having an issue when creating a bucket notification to trigger a Lambda function. The error:

```
Error putting S3 notification configuration: InvalidArgument: Unable to validate the following destination configurations
    status code: 400
```

I've read that similar problems might be caused by the order in which the resources are created or that Lambda permissions are missing. However, I tried including `depends_on` in my code as well as applying the template couple of times and waiting in between. I'm using the least restrictive Lambda policy. I also tried using the exact sample code from the [Terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_notification), but that gives me a whole different error.

The exact same setup works fine if created in the console.

Here's the problematic part of my code:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "writeUsersToDB" {
  filename      = "writeUsersToDB.zip"
  function_name = "writeUsersToDB"
  role          = "arn:aws:iam::0000000:role/AWSLambdaFullAccess"
  handler       = "main.lambda_handler"
  memory_size = 256
  timeout = 900
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("writeUsersToDB.zip")
  runtime = "python3.8"
  environment {variables = local.parameters}
  layers = [ "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:0000000:layer:pandas-pandas-schema-numpy:1" ]
}



resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "event" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.user_data.id

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.writeUsersToDB.arn
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_suffix       = ".csv"
  }
  depends_on = [aws_lambda_function.writeUsersToDB]
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket" "user_data" {
  bucket = "nameofthebucket"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing [aws_lambda_permission](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_permission):

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "example" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.writeUsersToDB.function_name
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_s3_bucket.user_data.arn
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, that worked! I've been sitting on this for 3 days. But I'm confused now, why Lambda role wasn't enough?

Comment: @madej lambda functions have two types of permissions: execution role and resource-based permissions. What you write about is the first type. But here we need to specify second type, namely, what can invoke the function. In this case, we allow S3 to invoke it.